# Windbg- Crash dump

Tags: windbg, dump, crash-dumps

I have IIS crash dump of a .net web application. After doing dumpstack I got call stack:

```
00000000028fe8c0 000007fe9b6f2fe5 (MethodDesc 000007fe99e41878 +0x105 ABC.dll!Unknown), calling (MethodDesc 000007fef7634de0 +0 System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(System.Object, System.Object[]))
00000000028fe910 000007fe9a075b68 (MethodDesc 000007fe9a667460 +0x38 XYZ.dll!Unknown), calling (MethodDesc 000007fef7553ff8 +0 System.Activator.CreateInstance[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]]())
```

I want to know actual method which stack pointing to. How to get this using windbg?

Comment: use !clrstack from sos.dll to see more

Comment: Don't use dumpstack.  As has been pointed out, use !sos.clrstack, !sosex.mk, or just the debugger "k" command.  The latest debuggers know how to interpret the managed stack.

Comment: @SteveJohnson: really? Since which version is that feature included?

Comment: @SteveJohnson  Yes, do tell!

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mistaken.  This feature is not included in the debuggers.

Comment: Did !sos.clrstack or !sosex.mk do what you needed?

Comment: Hi Issue was something else. I forgot to load pdb files which caused the issue. After loading, everything was fine.

Comment: Ok, maybe you want to delete the question then